# Sink inside Actor invoked during prod, but not during test

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest, akka-stream

I have an actor that invokes a stream. At runtime this works as intended, but when tested the stream is not invoked.

The Actor (abbreviated)

```
class PaymentProcessorActor(repo: PaymentRepo, accountCache: AccountCache, config: AppConfig) extends Actor {

  implicit private val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit private val network: Network = config.network
  private implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = context.dispatcher

  val paymentSink: Sink[(Seq[Payment], Account), NotUsed] =
    Flow[(Seq[Payment], Account)].map { case (ps, account) =>
      println("inside flow")
      // ... block of type Future[(TransactionResponse, Seq[Payment], Account)] here
    }
    .mapAsync(parallelism = config.accounts.size)(_.map {
      case ((_: TransactionApproved, ps), account) =>
        // handle approval

      case ((x: TransactionRejected, ps), account) =>
        // handle rejection
    })
    .to(Sink.ignore)

  override def receive: Receive = state(nextKnownPaymentDate = None)

  private def state(nextKnownPaymentDate: Option[ZonedDateTime]): Receive =
    processPayments(nextKnownPaymentDate) orElse
      updateNextPaymentTime orElse
      confirmPayments orElse
      rejectPayments orElse
      rejectTransaction orElse
      retryPayments orElse
      updateAccount orElse
      registerAccount


  // If there are payments due, find and pay them
  def processPayments(nextKnownPaymentDate: Option[ZonedDateTime]): PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case ProcessPayments if nextKnownPaymentDate.exists(_.isBefore(ZonedDateTime.now())) =>
      val readyAccounts = accountCache.readyCount
      if (readyAccounts > 0) {
        val payments = repo.due(readyAccounts * 100)
        if (payments.isEmpty) {
          logger.debug("No more payments due.")
          context.become(state(repo.earliestTimeDue))
        } else {
          val submittingPaymentsWithAccounts: Seq[(Seq[Payment], Account)] =
            payments.grouped(100).flatMap(ps => accountCache.borrowAccount.map(ps -> _)).toSeq
          val submittingPayments: Seq[Payment] = submittingPaymentsWithAccounts.flatMap(_._1)
          repo.submit(submittingPayments.flatMap(_.id), ZonedDateTime.now)

          Source.fromIterator(() => submittingPaymentsWithAccounts.iterator).to(paymentSink).run()
          println("post source run")
        }
      }
  }
```

The spec. (`sampleOf` just creates a random instance and is not pertinent to the problem).

```
  "the payment sink" should {
    "submit to the network" in {
      val (network, conf, repo, cache) = setup
      val account = sampleOf(genAccount)
      val payments = sampleOf(Gen.listOfN(3, genPayment))
      when(repo.earliestTimeDue).thenReturn(Some(ZonedDateTime.now()))
      when(repo.due(100)).thenReturn(payments)

      val actor = system.actorOf(Props(new PaymentProcessorActor(repo, cache, conf)))

      // these two calls set up the actor state so that payments will be processed
      actor ! UpdateNextPaymentTime
      actor ! UpdateAccount(account)

      // this invokes the stream under test
      actor ! ProcessPayments

      eventually(timeout(5 seconds)) {
        assert(network.posted.size == 1)
      }
    }
  }

  private def setup: (StubNetwork, AppConfig, PaymentRepo, AccountCache) = {
    val n = StubNetwork()
    val conf = new AppConfig {
      val network: Network = n
      val accounts: Map[String, KeyPair] = Map.empty
    }
    val repo = mock[PaymentRepo]
    (n, conf, repo, new AccountCache)
  }
```

At runtime, I see the stdout messages:

```
post source run
inside flow
```

But during test I only see

```
post source run
```

With debugging, I see that all values are correct and the source `.run` is called. But somehow it does not run.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but at "inside flow" why would you create a `Future` in a `map` rather than doing a `mapAsync` here? I sort of suspect there's blocking on the dispatcher somewhere, but don't see it here directly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ArnoutEngelen. I call out to a library function which returns a `Future`. The full block being https://github.com/0rora/0rora/blob/ba373e/app/models/PaymentProcessor.scala#L50-L56 Does that look problematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `.mapAsync(parallelism = config.accounts.size)`, the value was zero, which is an error condition. The `Flow` never initialised. This failure does not propagate to the main thread.

Additionally, I had turned off Akka logging for tests in the configuration, so this failure was not logged.

Comment: Just add a supervision strategy while creating a materializer to log the errors, like: 
`ActorMaterializerSettings(actorSystem).withSupervisionStrategy(decider)`
and decider will be:
    `decider: Supervision.Decider = { case ex: Exception =>`
     ` logger.error(s"Unhandled exception in stream: $ex")`
      `Supervision.Stop`
`    }`